# Apprequest Dialog stopped working (FB-AS3 API)

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, apprequests, facebook-actionscript-api

I'm writing ActionScript game and wanted to integrate it with FB, so I used http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/ with custom dialog function I've found in same issue thread. It goes like this:

```
    protected function dialog(method:String, callback:Function, stageReference:Stage, stageWebView:StageWebView, params:* = null):void {
        dialogCallback = callback;
        stageRef = stageReference;

        webView = stageWebView;
        webView.stage = stageReference;

        webView.assignFocus();

        dialogWindow = new DialogWindow(handleDialog);
        dialogWindow.open(method, applicationId, webView, params);
    }
```

I've written module to handle all the FB  stuff and it worked perfectly.
But few days ago I've noticed that dialog shows up, but when I select friends and try to send apprequest to them i get error:

```
An error occurred with your app. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 2
API Error Description: Service temporarily unavailable
Error Message: User can't send this request: Unknown error
```

I've checked it, and found out, that after selecting friends and clicking send dialog changes location to `http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequest`, the error occures, and than after clicking "ok" it changes location to redirect_uri.

Do you have any ideas? Is this my fault or facebooks'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, the apprequests are currently broken: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/540196825997304

Answer (score 0):

For apprequest i used this

> ```
> function invite(evt:MouseEvent):void
> {
>           var obj:Object = 
>           {
>               message: "aaa",//max 255
>               title: "bbb"//max 50
>           };
>           Facebook.ui("apprequests", obj, callback, "iframe");
> }
>
> function callback(res):void
> {
>
> }
> ```